# Functions and procedures used by current user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to find the procedures used by me (current user) in pl/sql?
I mean, I would like to do it with a view or something.

```
SELECT * FROM  USER_SOURCE WHERE USER = 'myuser';
```

The problem is with user = 'myuser'. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: added oracle tag, since you mentioned `pl/sql`

Comment: What do you mean by "*used* by me"?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then you should check against `owner` column like

```
SELECT * FROM  ALL_SOURCE WHERE OWNER = 'myuser';
```

`OWNER` column means `Owner of the object`. So, with the above query you will get stored objects owned by you or `myuser` but that will not let you know whether that stored objects have recently been used or not.

See here [ALL_SOURCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm#i1588578)

**EDIT:**

Not sure why you are getting that strange error but still you can get Functions and procedures accessible to current user by using `user_source` table like

```
SELECT * FROM  USER_SOURCE 
WHERE type in ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION');
```

Comment: I guess you are right, but now I get: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier

Comment: @user140102, that's strange. just change it to `owner = 'myuser'`

Comment: @user140102, BTW which version you are using? also, check whether you have permission to query that `all_source` view?

Comment: Same thing is happening. I'm using Version 4.0.0.13. I have the permissions. When I put "where 1 = 1" is working.

Comment: @user140102, just do `select * from ALL_SOURCE` and see if `owner` column is present or not.

Comment: Yup. Owner is SYS, the name that I used in querry.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way to monitor sql execution is using V$SQL and V$SQLTEXT views.

```
SELECT
   module, 
   sql_text , 
   u.username
  FROM
   sys.v_$sql s, 
   sys.all_users u 
  WHERE
   s.parsing_user_id = u.user_id 
   and UPPER(u.username) = UPPER('YOUR_USER_NAME') 
   -- AND S.SQL_TEXT like '%SOME PROCUDER NAME%'
```

To be more specific for a given procedure you may use [ORACLE AUDITING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF53656).

```
audit execute on PROCEDUR_NAME by session;
```

After several calls to the procedure you can see the execution log by:

```
select username, owner, obj_name, action_name 
from dba_audit_trail where obj_name = 'PROCEDUR_NAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  grantee, owner, table_name, type, grantor, privilege 
FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS 
WHERE upper(grantee) in ('PUBLIC', 'MYUSER');
```